# How can i execute Neo4j backup command using KuberenetesClient in .Net core/c#?

Tags: c#, .net, kubernetes, neo4j

I have written the following .Net core/C# code to execute the Neo4j backup command using Neo4j-admin tool through KubernetesClient. However, it is returning neither any successful result nor any error, instead it is returning only \0\0\0\0.....

```
private static async Task ExecInPod(IKubernetes client)
        {
            try
            {
                var webSocket =
                    await client.WebSocketNamespacedPodExecAsync("server1-0", "neo4j5", "neo4j-admin database backup --to-path=/var/lib/neo4j/data/backup --from=127.0.0.1:6362 --include-metadata=all --expand-commands neo4j").ConfigureAwait(false);

                var demux = new StreamDemuxer(webSocket);
                demux.Start();

                var buff = new byte[4096];
                var stream = demux.GetStream(1, 1);
                var read = stream.Read(buff, 0, 4096);
                var str = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(buff);
                Console.WriteLine(str);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
    }
```

Has someone gone through same situation earlier or a mitigation plan from anyone would be appreciated.